# Isn't this answer spam?

Tags: support, declined-flags, spam

My spam flag was rejected on this answer:

[Magento - Importing Configurable Products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423631/magento-importing-configurable-products/24424176#24424176)

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

It's only promoting an external product. Now I don't know for the next time if I should flag similar spam answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I declined the flag because there was no evidence that the poster was affiliated with the project.

I took the fact that it was a Source Forge project into account as well.

@user0000000 is also correct. The question should be closed.

Comment: Then I shouldn't flag promoting-only answers of external products when the user doesn't seem related with the project itself? What is the rule? When is open-source and "looks like" not related to the user then is allowed? (I'm not intending to sound rude, just want to know how to proceed)

Comment: @SysDragon - You should flag if you think it's spam. However, we have to look at the wider picture (we have access to more information than you) when dealing with the flag so there might be other information that makes us think it's not spam.

Answer (score 5):

The question is off topic because it's asking for a resource.

So the question should be closed.

However, the answer provides a resource to the question.

So the reason the answer stinks, is because the question does.

But the answer does answer the question, so that is why your flag was rejected.

If the question didn't ask for a resource, then it was the correct flag.

So just make sure to read the question before flagging an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So if the question is asking for resources the answers itself can't be spam? I don't think it should be a bad flag just because the question is off-topic. If you can't answer that in SO then you can't, and if you find that kind of questions, instead of posting an answer that goes against the policy of the site (but correct), you should vote to close the question or whatever, or your question can get flagged, isn't it?

Comment: I still think this kind of questions shouldn't be answered, neither reward answering them with correct answers against the policy of the site